# Will a software update through ClickOnce change the path of the installed application?

Tags: clickonce, litedb

I've deployed an application using ClickOnce. The application auto-creates a LiteDb database if it does not exist.

Now, I wanted to deploy an update to the application without replacing the LiteDb database. The application won't replace the LiteDb file if it exists, but it has to be installed (or updated) in the same folder.

**My question - Will the update change the path of the installed application?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

I have tested it. A new folder will be created to install the latest version.

The solution to the problem is to create a folder path and save it as a setting in the app, so regardless of the app updates, it will still point to the shared folder path held in the setting.